# Tkinter: KeyError when assigning function to a button

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, text, keyerror

So, I have rather complicated program, and I ran into an issue with it that I can't seem to solve.
Here's the problematic part of my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
variable = "enter"
vars()[variable] = tk.Entry()
vars()[variable].insert(0, "hello")
vars()[variable].pack()

def hi():
    text = vars()[variable].get()

button = tk.Button(text = "Click", command = hi)
button.pack()
```

I need to get the content of the entry called "enter" with the press of a button. Because of how my program works, this name, "enter" must be stored in a variable, that I called "variable" here.
What happens, is that when I press the button, I get a KeyError.

What's even weirder is that when I do the following, the program actualy works:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
variable = "enter"
vars()[variable] = tk.Entry()
vars()[variable].insert(0, "hello")
vars()[variable].pack()


text = vars()[variable].get()

button = tk.Button(text = "Click")
button.pack()
```

Here getting the content of "enter" isn't done with a button, but it's done automatically as the program runs. This is not what I want, but for some reason it works.

What can I do to make the 1st code work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `vars` locally within `hi` function, a new dict object is created, that is different than the dict object created globally.
You can save the reference to the variable and use the variable within your `hi` function.

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
variable = "enter"
vars()[variable] = tk.Entry()
vars()[variable].insert(0, "hello")
vars()[variable].pack()

d = vars()

def hi():
    text = d[variable].get()

button = tk.Button(text="Click", command=hi)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the content of the entry called "enter" with the press of a button. Because of how my program works, this name, "enter" must be stored in a variable,

A better solution than using `vars()[variable]` is to store your widgets in a dictionary. The use of `vars()` provides very little value at the expense of making the code harder to understand.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
variable = "enter"

widgets = {}
widgets[variable] = tk.Entry()
widgets[variable].insert(0, "hello")
widgets[variable].pack()

def hi():
    text = widgets[variable].get()
    print(text)

button = tk.Button(text = "Click", command = hi)
button.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try to re-write the code with dictonaries.